How does the surface code have four twist defects, one at each corner?
In Craig Gidney’s Y Basis paper he states “Recall that a surface code patch has four twist defects, one at each corner” and cites Ben Brown et al.’s ‘Poking’ paper. I do not understand how to manipulate twist defects to the corners and defect lines to the boundary in order to arrive at the usual planar surface code, which from my understanding the paper suggests is possible as these two surface codes are “equivalent”. Here are the relevant figures and their descriptions:
Fig. 1 in Brown’s paper shows the usual (planar) surface code which encodes a single logical qubit

Fig. 3 shows a single surface code patch with all all Z-type (“rough”) boundaries that encodes a logical qubit using two pairs of twist defects (marked in grey) joined by lines of deleted qubits in pink

Fig. 4 explains a schematic for visualising such surface codes, where X’s mark twist defects joined by dashed defect lines:

And finally Fig. 5 uses the schematic to explain how we can get from the twist-defect surface code in Fig. 3 (corresponding to Fig. 5 (a) to the usual planar surface code in Fig. 1 (corresponding to Fig. 5 (d) ) namely by moving the twist defects to the corners and the defect lines to the boundaries:
.
After moving the twist defects to the corners and the defect lines to the boundaries they they state “the logical operators are now identical to those of the planar code, where $\bar{Z}$ corresponds to moving an $e$ excitation from
the upper boundary to the lower boundary, and $\bar{X}$ corresponds to moving an $m$ excitation from the left boundary to the right boundary. In this sense, we can regard a smooth (X-type) boundary as a rough (Z-type) boundary that has been covered by a defect line. We also observe that the points, or corners, where the rough boundary meets the smooth boundary are
the locations of twist defects. We can therefore regard the
corners of the planar code as equivalent to twist defects.”
If I try to draw a rough-boundary surface code and cover a rough boundary with a defect line (below) I’m not sure how it naturally turns into the regular planar surface code and I am also not sure how to go from the weight-5 twist defect stabilisers XXYZZ to the meeting of smooth and rough boundaries in the planar surface code:

